# Cannot use apt to install gcc-9-base

Tags: ubuntu, apt, virtualbox

I am running ubuntu 19.04 (disco) in the latest VirtualBox and all was running fine until I tried to upgrade `LBLIBCXX_3.4.21` to fix the error below. I used `dpkg` to force install `lib64stdc++6_9.1.0-2ubuntu2_19.04_i386.deb`. Then after reading it complain about `gcc-9-base` being out of date, I tried `apt install gcc-9-base` that only returns the following error message.

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I tried the following suggestions but could not find a solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6

What do I need to do to get `apt install` working again?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that have gone wrong here. Since `apt` is showing an error concerning `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0`, you’re presumably using `amd64`, not `i386`, so you should re-install the `amd64` package of `libstdc++6` and remove the `i386` package you force-installed.

You can download the packages you need directly:

- [`libstdc++6`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libstdc++6_9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04_amd64.deb) (from [`gcc-9`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-9));
- if `apt` is still broken, [`libapt-pkg5.0`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libapt-pkg5.0_1.8.3_amd64.deb) (from [`apt`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt)).

Install them with `dpkg`, forcing if necessary (packages should never be force-installed, but fixing a forced installation often involves more force-installing).

Answer (score 0):

After reading my `.bash_history` file, I learned I had attempting to install libstdc++6 modules for a different reason, to unpack my android apk files. Once I realized how many different attempts I tried to get java and dex files to operate with libstdc++6, I decided it would be better to restart my build with a clean build instead of recovering from my failed attempts. I appreciate the suggested solution but because of the overwhelming version changes since 2017 in android, my whole project was aborted due to hardware and internet services deprecation. Ubuntu was the only possible option to make it possible. Unfortunately, the destination IoT android tablet platform has been bricked by Google Photos API deprecation.